# Need help with bindfs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: bind

I'm at my wits end trying to get bindfs to work.
I want to use /var/www/html for my web sites but because of permissions issue I decided to use bindfs. So I typed.

```
ls -l /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 26 09:20 html
```

I made directories as follows with owner joe.

```
/home/joe/websites/thermos
```

I then tried this:

```
sudo bindfs -o create-with-perms=0770, force-group=joe, force-user=joe, create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data /var/www/html/thermos /home/joe/websites/thermos
```

The error I got is:

```
Failed to resolve source directory `force-group=joe,': No such file or directory
```

I've googled for a similar error but could not find any.
I'm really puzzled at what I'm doing wrong.
Tried *bindfs* with and without sudo but got same error.
I did not try the *fstab* method, just wanted to keep things simple.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying the parameters the other way?

```
sudo bindfs --create-with-perms=0770 --force-group=joe --force-user=joe --create-for-user=www-data --create-for-group=www-data /var/www/html/thermos /home/joe/websites/thermos
```

Answer (score 0):

When entering your `bindfs` command avoid spaces between the parameters like this:

```
sudo bindfs -o create-with-perms=0770,force-group=joe,force-user=joe,create-for-user=www-data,create-for-group=www-data /var/www/html/thermos /home/joe/websites/thermos
```